# Exercise 8.5.6 Generic chaining: tail bound

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes

I'm studying Vershynin's [High-dimensional probability book](https://www.math.uci.edu/%7Ervershyn/papers/HDP-book/HDP-book.pdf).

> Theorem 8.5.5 (Generic chaining: tail bound).Let $(X_{t})_{t \in T}$  be a random process
> on a metric space (T,d) with sub-gaussian increments as in (8.1).Then, for every
> $u \geqslant 0$,the event
> $$
> \sup_{t,s\in T}|X_{t}  -  X_{s}|  \leqslant  CK[ \gamma_{2}(T,d)+u\cdot diam(T)]
> $$

Exercise 8.5.6. Prove Theorem 8.5.5.To this end, state and use a variant of the increment bound (8.44) with $u+2^{k / 2}$ instead of $u 2^{k / 2}$. In the end of the argument, you will need a bound on the sum of steps $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} d\left(\pi_k(t), \pi_{k-1}(t)\right)$. For this, modify the chain $\left\{\pi_k(t)\right\}$ by doing a **"lazy walk"** on it. Stay at the current point $\pi_k(t)$ for a few steps (say, $q-1$ ) until the distance to $t$ improves by a factor of 2 , that is until

> $$
> d\left(t, \pi_{k+q}(t)\right) \leq \frac{1}{2} d\left(t, \pi_k(t)\right)
> $$

then jump to $\pi_{k+q}(t)$. This will make the sum of the steps geometrically convergent.

**I know** about "lazy walk" :
$$  
d(\pi_k(t),\pi_{k+1}(t))=d(\pi_{k+1}(t),\pi_{k+2}(t))=\cdots=d(\pi_{k+q-1}(t),\pi_{k+q}(t))=0
$$

$$
d(\pi_{0}(t),\pi_{q}(t))\leq d(\pi_{0}(t),t)+d(\pi_{q}(t),t) \leq \frac32 d(\pi_{0}(t),t)
$$

$$
d(\pi_{q}(t),\pi_{q+q_{1}}(t)) \leq \frac12\cdot\frac32 d(\pi_{0}(t),t)
$$
**Question**:

> how to bound  on the sum of steps $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} d\left(\pi_k(t), \pi_{k-1}(t)\right)$ by "lazy walk" ?

**New**

> Theorem 2.2.27 in [Upper and Lower Bounds for Stochastic Processes: Modern Methods and Classical Problems](https://libgen.li/ads.php?md5=a762239aa4bf7f3cd03bb68b74c608ae) written by Michel Talagrand is the procedure for proving the exercise.
> Theorem 2.7.13 in [Upper and Lower Bounds for Stochastic Processes: Decomposition Theorems](http://library.lol/main/74245BE46CCBEA4F13BA37AEFF346E94) also written by Michel Talagrand